# Filtering rx.Observable response into two different subscribers

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm coding an Android App. I'm using Retrofit with RxJava in my network layer. Basically the issue that I have is that I have an endpoint called `/feed`. This endpoint returns a collection of articles that I show in a RecyclerView. Some of those articles are Ads articles, some are Events and others are Posts. I'm using a clean architecture, so I have an Interactor per each thing that I want to do. This is how my `GetFeedInteractor` looks like:

```
@Override
public void execute(final Callback callback, int offset, int pageSize) {
    final String userSipId = mUserSipid.get();

    mFeedRepository.getFeed(offset, pageSize)
            .subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<List<BaseFeedItem>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<BaseFeedItem> baseFeedItems) {
                    List<BaseFeedItem> cacheCollection = new ArrayList<BaseFeedItem>();

                    for (BaseFeedItem baseFeedItem : baseFeedItems) {
                        if (!(baseFeedItem instanceof AdFeedItem)) {
                            cacheCollection.add(baseFeedItem);
                        }
                    }

                    mFeedCache.saveFeeds(cacheCollection);

                    callback.onFeedsFetched(baseFeedItems);
                }
            });
}
```

As you can see the Callback that I use to show the items in the UI takes all the three types of Feeds and shows them. But I need to save only the Post articles and the Event articles in a Sqlite Cache. The thing is that I don't like doing that for instanceof inside the Subscriber. Is there some better Rx-way of doing this?

#### Update:

BTW I use the FeedCache#saveFeed method in several places, but only here is where I can get Ads Articles. So doing the Ad filtering inside the FeedCache#saveFeed is not a good choice.

#### Update2:

I think that the perfect solution for this would be if I could filter the collection using some of the Rx-methods, and have a Subscriber that handles the raw list, and another that handles the ad-filtered list. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you want to 2 streams out of one stream. One will be the raw stream (for displaying UI), and the other will be a filtered stream (for saving in database). Unfortunately, you cannot have multiple `onSubscribe`s, but we can use the concept of [`Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject)s.

```
final PublishSubject<BaseFeedItem> subject = PublishSubject.create();

subject.subscribe(o -> {
    // here will be emitted all items
    // update the UI
});

mFeedRepository.getFeed(offset, pageSize)
               .map(item -> {
                    subject.onNext(item);
                    return item;
                })
               .filter(item -> !(item instanceof AdFeedItem))
               .subscribe(items -> {
                   // no `AddFeedItem`s here
                   // save into database
               });
```

Comment: Yeah but notice that I need to handle the raw respone and the filtered reponse separatedly. One one hand I need to filter the collection and save it into the cache. On the other hand, I need to send the full raw collection to the UI through the callback. In your example you're only filtering the collection and that's it, where I can hook to get the full raw collection?. Please let know if you have any doubt, maybe I didn't explain myself very well.

Comment: Nice, I'll dig a litte more to see if I can make it fit. Also I wanna wait a little bit longer in case that someones comes up with a better approach. Thanks this is really useful.